# MVC RC Validation: Is this right?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, binding, html-helper

I'm just trying to do some simple validation in MVC RC and am getting an error.  For the purposes of this question, I am **not using the UpdateModel**.

Here is the code in the form:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("UserId")%>
<%= Html.ValidationMessage("UserId") %>
```

If I add the following line in the controller, I will get a NullReferenceException on the TextBox:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("UserId", "*");
```

So to fix this, I've also added the following line:

```
ModelState.SetModelValue("UserId", ValueProvider["UserId"]);
```

Why am I having to rebind the value?  **I only have to do this if I add the error**, but it seems like I shouldn't have to do this.  I feel like Im doing something incorrectly or just not familiar enough with binding.

It looks like Im not the only one who has seen this.  Per request, here is the controller code:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {
        AppUser newUser = new AppUser();

        try
        {
            newUser.UserId = collection["UserId"];

            AppUserDAL.AddUser(newUser);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewData["ReturnMessage"] = ex.Message;

            ModelState.AddModelError("UserId", "*");
            ModelState.SetModelValue("UserId", ValueProvider["UserId"]);


            return View(newUser);
        }
```

Comment: I also noticed this and I just wrote it off as something I did wrong and continued on with other work.

Comment: Could you please add a full code of page and of the controller's method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call this extension method:

```
        public static void AddModelError (this ModelStateDictionary modelState, string key, string errorMessage, string attemptedValue) {
        modelState.AddModelError (key, errorMessage);
        modelState.SetModelValue (key, new ValueProviderResult (attemptedValue, attemptedValue, null));
    }
```

From: [Issues with AddModelError() / SetModelValue with MVC RC1](http://www.crankingoutcode.com/2009/02/01/IssuesWithAddModelErrorSetModelValueWithMVCRC1.aspx)

Comment: Ok, it looks like this is a problem with RC1.  This will work, although it seems a little heavy handed.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: we'll see if this is fixed in the 1.0 release

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't need to call SetModelValue.

Perhaps you just need your view to pull the Textbox from the model you passed in?

```
<%= Html.TextBox("UserId", Model.UserId)%>
```

That's how I do it.

Comment: I tried this and it doesnt appear to work either.  What's strange is that when I mouse over the line of code in the View that breaks, the Model object is not null and I can see all of the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this extension to set the model value with a lambda expression:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets model value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TViewModel">The type of the view model.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TProperty">The type of the property</typeparam>
    /// <param name="me">Me.</param>
    /// <param name="lambdaExpression">The lambda expression.</param>
    ///<param name="value">New Value</param>
    public static void SetModelValue<TViewModel, TProperty>(
        this ModelStateDictionary me,
        Expression<Func<TViewModel, TProperty>> lambdaExpression,
        object value)
    {

        string key = WebControlsExtensions.GetIdFor<TViewModel, TProperty>(lambdaExpression, ".");

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key))
        {
            me.SetModelValue(key, new ValueProviderResult(value, String.Empty, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }
    }
```

To get the id:

```
public static class WebControlsExtensions
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Devuelve el Id correspondiente a la expresión lambda pasada por parámetro reemplazando los caracteres inválidos por la cadena pasada por parámetro
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TViewModel">El tipo del modelo</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TProperty">El tipo de la propiedad</typeparam>
    /// <param name="expression">Expresión lambda</param>
    /// <param name="invalidCharReplacement">Cadena de texto que reemplaza a los carácteres inválido</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Valid characters consist of letters, numbers, and the hyphen ("-"), underscore ("_"), and colon (":") characters. 
    /// All other characters are considered invalid. Each invalid character in originalId is replaced with the character specified in the HtmlHelper.IdAttributeDotReplacement property.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <returns> Devuelve el Id correspondiente a la expresión lambda</returns>
    public static string GetIdFor<TModel, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string invalidCharReplacement)
    {
        return TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression), invalidCharReplacement);
    }

}
```